# How can I update the item of recyclerview when I come back to list in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I have an `Activity` and in this `Activity`, it shows a list of items with the help of `RecyclerView`, `Adapter` and fetches the items from a database.

In the database I have a table called `Place` with 7 Fields one of the fields is `interest` with Default Value 0 and Integer data type.

When I click an item in the list, this opens new `Activity` with all details of that item. One of the details is `interest`. The c
value of `interest` with `Star` icon. If the Value is 0 icon is Black otherwise it is Gold.

That part works fin. When I click the `Star` icon, the icon and the value of `interest` field in database successfully changes. However, my issue is :

When I come back to the `Activity` displaying the list of items and go back to that particular item, the changes of `Star` icon are not reflected. Example: first the icon is black, I change the icon by clicking on it to change to gold and update the value of `interest` field to 1. Only when I close the app completely and re-open again, the changes are shown correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: @UltimateDevil correct , ok.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass back changed Place object from All Details Activity to items list Activity and then notify and change the item in the adapter.

First, you have to start an activity with listening on results:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AllDetailsActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("place", place);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1000)
```

When you change and confirm changes on All details screen you have to return changed object and result like this:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("returned_place", place));
```

Then you have to implement **onActivityResult** inside Activity where you have a list of objects like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if(request == 1000 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        adapter.changeItem(position, (Place) data.getExtras().get("returned_place"))
     }
}
```

And adapter function for changing items should be something like this:

```
public void changeItem(int position, Place place) {
    items.set(position, place);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

You also have to save the position of the clicked Place object to know which cell you have to update.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method from your adapter if you are not sure at what position of your data in the recyclerView you are in.

It is however better to call the `notifyItemChanged(position)` method from your adapter to only update the view for that specific recyclerView object.

Comment: in adapter i can send the position of item to second activity and when come back to first activity in onActivityResult method i call the notifyItemChanged(position) correct ??

Comment: If I understand you correctly yes, we do not have any code snippets from you so it makes the question a bit more difficult.